# Partir una cadena por numero de caracteres y añadir caracteres en python

Tags: python

he creado un script en python para enviar tramas a una controladora. Actualmente la trama referente al texto a enviar la creo de manera manual, pero me gustaría crearla de forma automática, y no encuentro qué funciones utilizar.

Os pongo ejemplo:

```
Text = '123'
Texto1 = binascii.hexlify(Text.encode())
Resultado:'313233'
```

Debido a parámetros de color y alineación (supongamos que hay que añadir 00 00), debería partir cada la trama y dejarla de la siguiente manera:
000031000032000033

Y no soy capaz de conseguir esto...

Answer (score 1):

Una solución puede ser crear tu propia versión de `binascii.hexlify()` que te permita especificar cuántas cifras quieres en la conversión a hexadecimal, para que rellene con ceros por la izquierda hasta completar ese número de cifras (seis en tu caso).

Una función así podría ser la siguiente:

```
def mi_hexlify(data, num_cifras=6):
  fmt = "{{:0{}x}}".format(num_cifras)
  return "".join(fmt.format(byte) for byte in data)
```

Que podrías usar así:

```
Text = '123'
Texto1 = mi_hexlify(Text.encode())
```

Lo que da el resultado `'000031000032000033'` que querías.

## Explicación

He usado la función `str.format()` para dar formato hexadecimal a cada uno de los bytes de `data`. Primero creo una cadena que he llamado `fmt` con esta línea:

```
  fmt = "{{:0{}x}}".format(num_cifras)
```

La doble llave sirve para que python no la interprete como un *placeholder* en el que poner un valor, sino que dé como resultado una llave normal. Las otras llaves más internas entre el `0` y la `x` sí serán un *placeholder* que se sustituye por el valor del parámetro `num_cifras`. De este modo, si `num_cifras` es 6, la cadena resultante en `fmt` será `"{:06x}"`.

Esta cadena se usa después para formatear cada uno de los bytes de `data`.
La cadena de formato `{:06x}` indica que el dato sea convertido a hexadecimal (eso es la `x`) y que ocupe al menos seis cifras rellenando con ceros por la izquierda si son menos (eso es el `06`).

La expresión: `(fmt.format(byte) for byte in data)` es una *expresión generadora* que Python va evaluando sucesivas veces para obtener un elemento de cada vez. En tu ejemplo, los sucesivos elementos que se irían obteniendo serían `"000031"` , `"000032"` y `"000033"`.

Esa secuencia de elementos es la que se pasa como parámetro a `"".join()` para que los concatene creando así una única cadena que es lo que la función retorna.

#### Cuidado

Una diferencia entre la función que he escrito y la función `binascii.hexlify()`, además de los ceros de relleno, es que la mía retorna una cadena de caracteres, mientras que `hexlify()` retornaba una cadena *de bytes*. La diferencia es importante según lo que después vayas a hacer con ella.

Si la vas a volcar a un archivo o enviar por un socket, debe ser una cadena de bytes, por lo que lo que te retorna `hexlify()` era ya directamente usable. En cambio lo que retorna `mi_hexlify()` habría que convertirlo a bytes antes de enviarlo, por ejemplo así:

```
s.send(Texto1.encode())
```

Si quieres podríamos hacer que `mi_hexlify()` retornara directamente la versión con bytes, con una leve modificación:

```
def mi_hexlify(data, num_cifras=6):
  fmt = "{{:0{}x}}".format(num_cifras)
  return "".join(fmt.format(byte) for byte in data).encode()
```

Esto ya depende de qué sea más apropiado para tu caso de uso.

## Edición

Las cadenas de formato permiten también poder especificar la longitud (el 6 en nuestro caso) sin tener que usar una cadena de formato intermedia como la que usé en la variable `fmt`. Para ello la cadena de formato "final" podría ser `"{:0{}x}"`, y en este caso `format()` llevaría dos parámtros: el dato a codificar y el número de caracteres a ocupar. Con esta sintaxis la función quedaría así:

```
def mi_hexlify(data, num_cifras=6):
  return "".join("{:0{}x}".format(byte, num_cifras) for byte in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución simple:

```
Text = '123'
t = ''.join([f"0000{hex(ord(x))[2:]}" for x in Text])
print(t)
```

**Explicación**

Dado un caracter ('1', por ejemplo), la función `ord` me retorna el valor ASCII en decimal:

```
ord('1') -> 49
```

Con `hex` lo convierto a hexadecimal:

```
hex(ord(x)) -> 0x31
```

Con `[2:]` descarto los dos primeros caracteres ('0x')

Eso convierte un caracter; para convertir una cadena, aplico compresión de listas:

```
[f"0000{hex(ord(x))[2:]}" for x in Text] -> ['000031', '000032', '000033']
```

Y finalmente junto todo con un `join`. El resultado es

```
000031000032000033
```